Macro for Moving large emails to PST
Request your kind support as i am not good in scripting. I am using gmail for mail communication and same is configured in outlook via imap settings.
As my gmail mailbox is frequently getting full due to lot of daily Reports emails. So i want to move daily reports emails which are older than 1 days to a particular folder in my local PST file.
So request your support in getting same thing achieved.

We're not a script-writing service. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Due to the limited ability of the individual to provide scripting services, as a workaround, you can use rules in Outlook to move these daily messages to a special folder, and automatically archive this folder. However, it is not recommended that you set the archive interval to one day, because it is likely to cause Outlook to lag and affect your rest of the operations.
In addition, maybe you'd like to know some other ways to manage mailbox size, and I found a similar thread where you might find some inspiration.

Thanks but Auto Archive doesnot work as required, thats why i am searching for a script which can help me achieve my requirement.

Please check your Auto Archive settings, ensure you have turned on and set the correct time range, as I know, Auto Archive is based on when the file was last modified. In addition, you may refer to this thread for some inspiration: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/autoarchive-doesnt-seem-to-work/b705d01d-88b9-49f7-ba44-d51c9aabfbe3
